# Custom assets balance of sender is not updating in stellar

Tags: stellar-sdk

I know this questions is already asked, but the solution provided is not proper.
So asking the question again.

We created a custom assets with name FOC. when we send any FOC to any account, the balance of asset is not being updated. we created 1000000000, and we have sent payments to other accounts as well, but the balance is not being updated.

You can see the balance here.

https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GD57ZNS2KGQWJMCUOSAVQH5QXBARDC3ISAK66I3SUYXPCDZ44G2FBD3P

You can see a payment transaction made here
https://steexp.com/account/GCUBPFP7PSJG7ZNLC64HAAKRB3E23OCUW2TJIJ4WYTPFXHKQEZQIC2YS#payments

but the balance is still same, we have done lots of other payment transactions but it keeps the same balance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asset issuer is different. The account has a balance of `FOC-GDK...` tokens, but the payment was a `FOC-GD5...` token payment. Since the trustline is for `FOC-GD5...` and the payment is also originated by `FOC-GD5...` those payments are new minted `FOC-GD5...` tokens, not the `FOC-GDK...` that the account holds.

You allways have to reference the asset_issuer/asset_name for your asset. Create a trustline for the asset_issuer, not for the sender/distributor.

---

Example:

- `GDK2G...` is the issuer
- `GCUBP...` is the distributor that got minted tokens from issuer
- `GCUBP...` is a user

Since distributor and user want to use your token, they all need a trustline to `FOC-GDK2G...`. Distributor already has it but your user has not. Once `GCUBP...` has the right trustline, `GCUBP...` can send him `FOC-GDK2G...` tokens.

`GCUBP...` has currently another trustline so it's minimum reserve is 1.5 XLM. It will need a minimum balance of 2 XLM for two trustlines, so you have to either delete the existing trustline first or charge it with some lumens to have 2 XLM.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried to change trust from this account GCUB... to this account GDK2....., this give me error

                            [transaction] => tx_failed
                            [operations] => 
                                (
                                    [0] => op_low_reserve
                             

Is this because for issuer account we Set Options after issuing the tokens?:
Master Weight=0
Low Threshold=0
......

Also, do you think after changing the trust we need to send payments from issuer account instead of sender/distributor?

Comment: Do I need to create new account for customer as the Trust has been already issue with Distributor account? or Trust can be change with Issuer account as well?

Comment: op_low_reserve means that the sender account has not enough XLM to keep the required XLM minimum reserve after deducting transaction fees.

Comment: an account may have multiple trustlines (only it's minimum reserve is increased by 0.5 XLM for every trustline), you can also delete a trustline with changeTrust( limit=0)

Comment: But you can see this account has GCUB.... enough XLM, and I am trying to issue trust from this GCUB....  to this GDK2.......

Comment: But GCUB already has a trust line, if you create another then the required minimum reserve would be increased by 0.5 to 2 XLM. I'll add an example to my answer in a minute or two...

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. I was able to make a transaction and balance is also get deducted.
Pasting the code of successful transaction, so it might help someone.
`$issuersourceKeypair = Keypair::newFromSeed($issuerstellar_pvt_key);
$FOCAsset = Asset::newCustomAsset('FOC', $issuersourceKeypair->getPublicKey());
$response = $server->buildTransaction($sourceKeypair)
->addCustomAssetPaymentOp($FOCAsset, $amount, $destinationKeypair)
->submit($sourceKeypair->getSecret());
$transaction_data = $response->getRawData();`